# How to profile plpgsql procedures

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, profiling, plpgsql

I'm trying to improve the performance of a long-running plpgsql stored procedure, but I have no idea what, if any, profiling tools are available.  Can anyone offer suggestions for how to go about profiling such a procedure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Raise some [notices](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html) from the procedure including the [clock_timestamp()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html) to see where the database spends time. And make the procedures a simple as possible.

Could you show us an example?

Comment: I was hoping for a method that wouldn't require changes to the procedure, but that would probably be better than nothing.  http://www.depesz.com/index.php/2010/03/18/profiling-stored-proceduresfunctions/ documents a similar procedure, but it seems overly complicated to get usable data.  The procedure is a set of nested loops used to create documents for a Solr data import handler query, if that helps any (probably not).

Comment: It's not a great way to do it, but it's the only way. That's also why it's important to keep things short and simple: short procedures are much easier to debug and profile, just like other code.

Comment: Unfortunately, the procedure is about as simple as it can get.  It walks a bunch of 1:n relationships by selecting some data, iterating over the n, selecting more data, iterating over nested 1:n relationships, then RETURN NEXT from the inner loop once a full row is ready.  Everything more complex than SELECT or FOR has already been put in other procedures.

Answer (score 2):

We are currently looking for a better answer to this question, and have stumbled across this tool: 
http://www.openscg.com/2015/02/postgresql-plpgsql-profiler/
Hosted at:
https://bitbucket.org/openscg/plprofiler

It claims to give you what you are looking for, including the total time spent on each line of the function. We have not investigated it further yet, but based on the author's claims, we are optimistic.

Answer (score 1):

To start with, you could turn on [logging of all statements](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-logging.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-LOGGING-WHEN#GUC-LOG-MIN-DURATION-STATEMENT) into the Postgres logfile. The log will contain the runtime for each statement. This way you can identify the slowest queries and try to optimize them.

But reading your comment to Frank's post I'd guess that the looping is your problem. Try to get rid of the looping and do everything in a single query. One statement that reads a lot of rows is usually more efficient than a lot of statements reading only a few rows.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use pg_stat_statements extension ( http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/pgstatstatements.html ).
It can show call number and total call time for all statements (including sub-statements within plpgsql procedures).

Answer (score 0):

The tool to use is https://github.com/bigsql/plprofiler

If you installed PostgreSQL using the PGDG yum repository, then installing `plprofiler` is very straightforward, just run the commands below but keep in mind it's only available for PostgreSQL versions 11 and higher (replace XX with your version number):

```
yum install plprofiler_XX-server plprofiler_XX-client plprofiler_XX
```

Then add the profiler extension to your database:

```
CREATE EXTENSION plprofiler;
```

Then to generate a profile report on a plpgsql function, run a command like this:

```
plprofiler run -U your_username -d your_database --command "SELECT * FROM your_custom_plpgsql_function()" --output profile.html
```